# Duplicate contents based on differnt url on same website is that bad for ranking

Tags: seo, google, duplicate-content, ranking, google-ranking

I have blog website and has hundreds of blog items and blog can be accessed via different URL, it is mentioned that duplicate contents on website affects google ranking, defining single url as canonical url in code can solve this problem or we should about such scenario.

in below mentioned example you can see that i can access same blog via 3 different url,

Example URL

1. www.example.com/blog/11/title-of-blog
2. www.example.com/blog/2018/11/title-of-blog
3. www.example.com/archive/year/11/title-of-blog

Based on above example its same blog accessible from three different url,

1. How will it affect my google ranking
2. And defining first url as canonical in code will solve this problem or we should avoid using multiple url for same page all together

What is the best practice that we should follow if we have multiple url for same page

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Please edit your question and make it more direct. E.g is there a cap on how many canonicals a page can have? if so how many? etc.

Comment: @SimonHayter, I have updated my question and added more details, hope this will give more clarity of what i am asking for

Comment: After reviewing your question with the edits you have made is not unique and therefore is duplicate. Please visit our help centre for further assistance.

Comment: didnt get your point?